# Tree traverse in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, tree

I'm trying to write a script to find out the non-responsive links of a web-page in python. While trying, i find out that python doesn't support multi child nodes. Is it true? or we can access the multi child nodes.

Below is my code snippet:

```
import httplib2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

status = {}
response = {}
output = {}

def get_url_status(url, count):
    global links
    links = []
    print(url)
    print(count)
    if count == 0:
        return output
    else:
        # if url not in output.keys():
        headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
        req = requests.get(url, headers)
        if('200' in str(req)):
            # if url not in output.keys():
            output[url] = '200';
            for link in BeautifulSoup(req.content, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a')):
                if 'href' in str(link):
                    links.append(link.get('href'))

            # removing other non-mandotary links
            for link in links[:]:
                if "mi" not in link:
                    links.remove(link)

            # removing same url
            for link in links[:]:
                if link.rstrip('/') == url:
                    links.remove(link)

            # removing duplicate links
            links = list(dict.fromkeys(links))
            if len(links) > 0:
                for urllink in links:
                    return get_url_status(urllink, count-1)

result = get_url_status('https://www.mi.com/in', 5)
print(result)
```

In this code it's only traversing to only the left nodes of the child and skipping rest. something like this.
[image]

And the output is not satisfactory and very very less compared to real.

```
{'https://www.mi.com/in': '200', 'https://in.c.mi.com/': '200', 'https://in.c.mi.com/index.php': '200', 'https://in.c.mi.com/global/': '200', 'https://c.mi.com/index.php': '200'}
```

I know, i'm lacking at multiple locations but i've never done something of this scale and this is my first time. So please excuse if this is a novice question.

Note: I've used mi.com just for the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, there's one obvious problem.

```
if len(links) > 0:
    for urllink in links:
        return get_url_status(urllink, count-1)
```

This snippet does **not** iterate over `links`. It has `return` in its iterative body which means it will only run for the first item in links, and immediately return it. There is another bug. The function returns just `None` instead of `output` if it encounters a page with no links before `count` reaches 0. Do the following instead.

```
if len(links):
    for urllink in links:
        get_url_status(urllink, count-1)
return output
```

And `if('200' in str(req))` is not the right way to check the status code. It will check for a substring '200' in the body, instead of only checking the status code. It should be `if req.status_code == 200`.

Another thing is that the function only adds responsive links to `output`. If you want to check for non-responsive links, don't you have to add links that do not return the 200 status code?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

status = {}
response = {}
output = {}

def get_url_status(url, count):
    global links
    links = []
    # if url not in output.keys():
    headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
    req = requests.get(url, headers)
    if req.status_code == 200:
        # if url not in output.keys():
        output[url] = '200'
        if count == 0:
            return output
        for link in BeautifulSoup(req.content, parse_only=SoupStrainer('a'), parser="html.parser"):
            if 'href' in str(link):
                links.append(link.get('href'))

        # removing other non-mandotary links
        for link in links:
            if "mi" not in link:
                links.remove(link)

        # removing same url
        for link in links:
            if link.rstrip('/') == url:
                links.remove(link)

        # removing duplicate links
        links = list(dict.fromkeys(links))
        print(links)
        if len(links):
            for urllink in links:
                get_url_status(urllink, count-1)
        return output

result = get_url_status('https://www.mi.com/in', 1)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks @Hurried-Helpful. Will try this and let you know. 
And yes, i'll add the links for other response code as well. I didn't add this in snippet as the code was already long. I think i'll achieve this by just adding `else: output[url] = req.status_code;`.

Comment: Hi @Hurried-Helpful, After modifications it's not reiterating and only executing for once. Is there a way to share the code and output.